# Size of a ViewController Containers UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I have a ViewController Container that is 400 high on the iphone5. When I use it on a iphone4 it squashes the view like it does to everything. In this case I want the view to appear the same size on all phones.

vc.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewForContainer;
```

vc.m

```
@synthesize viewForContainer

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = [viewForContainer frame];
    rect.size.height = 400;
    [viewForContainer setFrame:rect];
}
```

Why can't I just force the height like this?
 .. am I going to have to make a new storyboard for it?

Comment: If you are using auto layout, it will work if you give the view a height of 400, and have constraints to the sides and top of the view, but not one to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Select the view and choose Editor > Pin > Height. Now get rid of the unnecessary bottom constraint.

Long answer:

You really should stop everything you're doing and *understand* what you're doing - in particular, about autolayout. It's everywhere, by default, whether we like it or not, so one may as well know about it.

Comment: Thanks. Don't have time for the Long answer thesis is due soon.

Comment: Ah, yes, real life; I've heard of that. Well, when you have time, there's always my book: here's the section on constraints in the nib -  http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_constraints_in_the_nib

Comment: Cool. I've just set everything bar the buttons relative to the top so that on the 5 there is a white space between the last row and buttons. I might look at better layout when have the time. Thanks matt.

Comment: Yes, it's usually pretty easy to achieve an acceptable layout that works on the iPhone 4 and 5 screens. Personally I think the 5 screen is silly; most apps, since they must run on the 4, probably end up with some wasted space on the 5 as a result, and that seems perfectly fine.

Comment: I can agree on the silly size:) It looks nicer than the older phones. Sort of like looking at a 4:3 monitor after using a widescreen. But for me at least I have to hold the phone both hands or flick the phone up because I cant reach the top with my thumb, though I could do perfectly on the older phones. So it makes it hard for me to use any sort of navigation view style of app. Thats why I was using a container and putting it inline with the top where the old phone would be (there is a map in the background).